# How to use flask-socketio for python scripts which do not have http request

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have been following [this](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [this](http://www.shanelynn.ie/asynchronous-updates-to-a-webpage-with-flask-and-socket-io/) link to have communication between client and server. My basic idea is to pop up notifications which I am currently emitting from app.py(my flask application). But, I also have separate python scripts which do no have http requests. I want to send notifications to the client(browser) from these scripts also. So I was thinking of sending messages to app.py from my other python scripts and doing emit from app.py. Is there a better alternative to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking of sending messages to app.py from my other python scripts and doing emit from app.py

This is actually how Flask-SocketIO does this.

You have to run a message queue, typically Redis or RabbitMQ, that is accessible to your server and your external scripts. Then in your server, you create your `SocketIO` object as follows:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://')
```

And in your scripts, you create it as follows:

```
socketio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://')
```

Obviously you can change the message queue URL to match what you are using.

The first object is a fully enabled server, that attaches to your `app` Flask instance. The second, is a "write-only" object that can only emit, since it was not given a server to attach to).

When you emit from the external script, the script will post a message to the message queue, which will be picked up by the server and then carried out.

Comment: How do I access the data in the message queue?

Comment: You don't have to do this, Flask-SocketIO takes care of the writing and reading from the queue for you.

Comment: But it's writing a single data twice and sometimes four times. So I want to check if the Flask-SocketIO is writing/reading the data twice(four times) or the message queue actually has data twice. This is why I want to access the data in the message queue. Is there any way to check that?

Comment: This is a regular pub-sub channel with name `flask-socketio`. You can subscribe to see what goes on the queue, or use any monitoring tool for Redis.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the idea. I'm able to see the data after subscribing to the pub-sub channel. But after displaying the data on the browser, it's gone once we reload the browser. This was my main concern. Is there a way to store the data temporarily somewhere so that I can display it back even after I reload the web page?

Comment: No, the client should ask the server to resend the data by sending a Socket.IO event.